# Access 2007 forms with parameterized RecordSource

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I'm sure there's a simple solution to this, but it seems to elude me.

So I have a form with a RecordSource of `SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE id=[@id]`.  (Yes, I know `SELECT *` is evil; it's just an example).
Obviously the default behavior of this form is that upon opening, an input dialog will prompt for the "[@id]" value.  But what I would like to do is call this form from VBA and instead of having the input dialog pop up, go ahead and tell the form what [@id] is, so the dialog never pops up, and the form opens just as if [@id] where replaced by a value in the query.  I've tried the following so far...

```
Form_MyForm.RecordSource = String.Replace(Form_Form1.RecordSource, "[@id]", 1)
DoCmd.OpenForm "MyForm"
```

...and...

```
Form_MyForm.txtId.Value = 1
DoCmd.OpenForm "MyForm"
```

...and...

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "MyForm", acNormal, , "[@id]=" & 1
```

...but none of them seem to have the desired effect.  How do i do this?

Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if it's easier to drop the WHERE clause from your query:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1;
```

Then use the optional WhereCondition parameter with Openform to indicate which id value you want:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "MyForm", WhereCondition:="id = 1"
```

Comment: I knew it would be something easy!  Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't seem to work the same way for reports.  Is there something else I need to do for them?