# Can I create a pass-through query via VBA to call a parameterized tSQL UDF and send it a dynamic parameter to return results to Access?

Tags: vba, ms-access, parameter-passing, user-defined-functions

I currently have a SQL 2008 R2 database backend with an Access 2013 accdb front end with ODBC DSN-less connection and linked tables. In SQL I have many parameterized tSQL UDFs created to feed data into reports (currently working well in my Access 2010 adp frontend). The reports are complicated: multiple tSQL UDFs run calculations and then feed into a final UDF that feeds the respective report. I would like to keep the UDFs on the server – rewriting into Access queries would be a poor solution.
My problem is that I have not been able to figure out how to write the VBA correctly to send a pass-through query to call the tSQL UDF and give it a parameter, which would change for each report. I know pass-through queries are read-only, that’s ok. I’ve read that I can call a stored procedure (SP) from VBA, but can I call the UDF rather than having to convert each to a SP or create a SP just to call the UDF so that I could call the SP from VBA. Based on my research, I think I might have to either create a SP to call the UDF or convert the UDF to a SP to get the VBA to work (i.e., return results without error). Is this correct?

I found this discussion: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/898933f5-73f9-44e3-adb9-6aa79ebc948f/calling-a-sql-udf-from-access?forum=accessdev , but it has conflicting statements “You can't call a tSql udf from Access.”, and “You can use a passthrough query to call UDF's or stored procedures or anything else written in tsql.” Also, their code is written in ADO instead of DOA so it’s a bit cryptic to me since I’ve only written DAO so far, but the general gist that I got was they converted their UDF to a SP.

I found this article a great read, but again did not get a clear “yes” to my question:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb188204(v=sql.90).aspx

It may be possible to remove the parameter from the Server side and add it to the Access side similar to this [Access 2007 forms with parameterized RecordSource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3200470/access-2007-forms-with-parameterized-recordsource) , but wouldn't that cause Access to load the entire dataset before filtering, instead of processing on the Server side – possibly causing performance issues?

I can successfully create a pass-through query in the Access interface if I supply it with a constant parameter, for example “Select * from udf_FinalReport(2023)”, but what I really need is to be able to pass a dynamic parameter. For example, the parameter would be from Forms!Control![txtboxValue]. Can I do this? The following code is what I’m using– it works if I use a table name in the SQL (ex, “SELECT * FROM Table WHERE tblYear = “&intYear ) in line 9 so I feel like I have everything coded right, but when I put my UDF in the SQL like below I get the error #3131 “Syntax error in FROM clause.” (I did verify that I should not use the prefix schema (dbo.) – this gives error 3024 “could not find file”.) Is this user error or just plain telling me I can’t call a UDF this way?

```
1 Sub AnnualSummary()
2 Dim dbs As DAO.Database
3  Dim qdfPoint As DAO.QueryDef
4  Dim rstPoint As DAO.Recordset
5  Dim intYear As Integer
6  intYear = Reports!Annual_Delineation_Summary!txtYear
7 Set dbs = OpenDatabase("", False, False, "ODBC;DRIVER=sql server;SERVER=******;APP=Microsoft 
8 Office 2010;DATABASE=*******;Network=DBMSSOCN")
9 Set qdfPoint = dbs.CreateQueryDef("", "Select * from udf_AnnualReport(" & intYear& ")")
10 GetPointTemp qdfPoint
11 ExitProcedure:
12  On Error Resume Next
13    Set qdfPoint = Nothing
14    Set dbs = Nothing
15    Set rstPoint = Nothing
16 Exit Sub
17 End Sub
18
19 Function GetPointTemp(qdfPoint As QueryDef)
20  Dim rstPoint As Recordset
21  With qdfPoint
22   Debug.Print .Name
23   Debug.Print " " & .SQL
24   Set rstPoint = .OpenRecordset(dbOpenSnapshot)
25   With rstPoint
26     .MoveLast
27     Debug.Print " Number of records = " & _
28      .RecordCount
29     Debug.Print
30     .Close
31   End With
32  End With
33 End Function
```

I also tried writing the code a little differently, using the following instead of lines 5, 6, and 9. This also works when I use a table name in the select statement, but I get error #3131 when I use a UDF name:

```
 Set qdfPoint = dbs.CreateQueryDef("", "Parameters year int; Select * from Point_Info where 
 year(Sample_Date) = year")
 qdfPoint.Parameters("year").Value = intYear
```

Both code variations also work if I try use the name of a SQL View in the tSQL SELECT statement.

Comment: There are some very rough notes here ( http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/datamgmt/datadesign/sql-server-zipcode-latitude-longitude-pr/ ), my comments on Access are pretty far down the page, so search for Remou. It may give you a few ideas.

Comment: Thanks Fionnuala! Yes I was able to "call" the UDF using your suggestion, which supports what I'm starting to understand - ADO is a better language to use when talking to SQL?  I'm still struggling with ADO because I haven't figured out how to keep my UID and PWD out of the connection string (see my other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26923379/keeping-uid-and-pwd-out-of-an-ado-connection-string-in-an-odbc-dsn-less-database).  Any suggestions on that one?  :)

Comment: You cannot keep everything out, but a compiled Access front-end is fairly safe. I link tables etc based on a small sign-in form, so no-one gets unacceptable permissions. ADO is not necessarily better, it depends on what you want to do. For the most part, DAO is faster, so mix and match : )

Comment: For example, if I want Soundex, is may be easier and faster to feed it through ADO and parameters to SQL Server procedure, but if I just want some records, a linked table and DAO will work very well indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My consensus is using ADO language instead of DAO to write the pass-through query works well.  But, I have found that it is still probably better to execute a stored procedure than to try to call the UDF.  Here is the code that ended up working most smoothly for me:  (my ADO Connection uses Public variables strUID and strPWD)

```
   Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
   Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
   Dim strPoint As String

   strPoint = Forms!FRM_Vegetation_Strata!Point_ID

   Set cn = New ADODB.Connection

   cn.Open "Provider = sqloledb;Data Source=imperialis.inhs.illinois.edu;" & _
           "Initial Catalog=WetlandsDB_SQL;User Id=" & strUID & ";Password=" & strPWD

   Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
   With rs
      Set .ActiveConnection = cn
      .Source = "sp_Report_VegWorksheet '" & strPoint & "'"
      .LockType = adLockOptimistic
      .CursorType = adOpenKeyset
      .CursorLocation = adUseClient
      .Open
   End With

   Set Me.Recordset = rs
```

On a side note I found that to get set the .Recordset to fill a subform put this code in the "Open" event of the subform.

Then to clean up your connection:

```
Private Sub Form_Unload(Cancel As Integer)  'use "unload", not "close"
   'Close the ADO connection we opened
   Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
   Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
   Set cn = Me.Recordset.ActiveConnection
   cn.Close
   Set cn = Nothing
   Set rs = Nothing
   Set Me.Recordset = Nothing

End Sub
```

This approach does not work for populating a report.  "Set Me.Recordset" only works for forms.  I believe I will have to call a stored procedure then populate a temp table to use as the report recordset.

EDIT: I have found that I can call a SQL UDF or SP from VBA in Access using DOA.  This is particularly helpful when one wants to pull the data from a complicated SQL function/procedure and put it into an Access-side temp table.   See Juan Soto's blog https://accessexperts.com/blog/2012/01/10/create-temp-tables-in-access-from-sql-server-tables/#comment-218563 This code puts the info into a temp table, which is what I wanted to populate my reports.  I used his code example and the following to call the sub:
To execute as SP: `CreateLocalSQLTable "testTBL","exec dbo.sp_Report_WetDet_point '1617-1-1A'",False`
To call a UDF: `CreateLocalSQLTable "testTBL","Select * from dbo.QryReport_Main('1617-2-2A')",False`

Comment: I found this link from Juan Soto on Access Experts helpful: https://accessexperts.com/blog/2011/08/15/stored-procedure-guide-for-microsoft-access-part-2/

Comment: Also, I just found that Microsoft may not be supporting DOA in the future.  It is listed as "Obsolete - will be excluded from future product releases, do not use  when you write new applications." on the MSDN website: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810810.aspx#bkmk_DepMDAC_WDACComps

Comment: What is DOA (apart from Dead On Arrival) ? Do you mean DAO ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's the most efficient method of passing a variable parameter through a pass-through query into a function and returning the results to Access, as I am still relatively new to Access, but I came across this earlier when I was attempting a similar problem.
I managed it by creating a couple of pass-through queries that executed functions in SQL server and returned a result. I then made a small VBA script that re-wrote the pass-through queries with the new variable every time I wanted to change it, and executed them.

I got the result back out using OpenRecordset, and stored it as a string to use in the rest of my code.